# Can bowler bowl with two hands (left & right) in international cricket

Tags: rules, cricket, icc

Recently I've seen in domestic match there was one bowler (spinner) who used his both hands while delivering the ball?

I've doubt can it be possible in International Cricket.

Does ICC has any rule about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly legal, so long as the bowler informs the umpire before changing from bowling left-handed to right-handed or vice versa. Quoting [Law 21.1.1, Mode of delivery](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-21-no-ball/):

> The umpire shall ascertain whether the bowler intends to bowl right handed or left handed, over or round the wicket, and shall so inform the striker.
>
> It is unfair if the bowler fails to notify the umpire of a change in his/her mode of delivery.  In this case the umpire shall call and signal No ball.

There is nothing in any of the ICC Playing Conditions for Test Matches, One Day Internationals or T20 Internationals which overrides this.